# javascript colspan dynamically while delete cell?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

could anyone help me on my code?
I try to make a sample code on the following action:
1. when the user click on the button, the "hello" will take cell 1 and cell 2 while the other cell 3 to 10 will remain.
2. When the user click on the button again, nothing happen.

I try to set a flag to false after the user click on it to let nothing happen if user click again; however, it doesn't work at all. The user can click until the first row's cells deleted just left "hello".

Any solution in javascript or JQuery? I try to search for static variable in javascript but seem impossible.

Thank you in advance.

```
var flag = false;
function clickhere(){
    if(flag = true){
        var cell = document.getElementById('a');
        document.getElementById("row").deleteCell(1);
        cell.setAttribute("colspan", 2);
        cell.innerHTML = "hello";
        flag=false;
    }
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr id="row">
        <td id="a">1</td>
        <td id="b">2</td>
        <td id="c">3</td>
        <td id="d">4</td>
        <td id="e">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="f">6</td>
        <td id="g">7</td>
        <td id="h">8</td>
        <td id="i">9</td>
        <td id="j">10</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Click" onclick="clickhere();"/>
```

Comment: omg, how can I make such terrible mistake, I should practice it hardly, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of *opportunities* to address.  Firstly, your **if** is doing an assignment rather than a a comparison.  Since your **flag** is a boolean we can use it directly.  Secondly, your initial assignment and the one at the end of the function should probably be opposite.

Here is one way you might correct things.

```js
var flag = false;
function clickhere(){
  if(flag){ return; }
  flag = true;

  var cell = document.getElementById('a');
  document.getElementById("row").deleteCell(1);
  cell.setAttribute("colspan", 2);
  cell.innerHTML = "hello";
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr id="row">
    <td id="a">1</td>
    <td id="b">2</td>
    <td id="c">3</td>
    <td id="d">4</td>
    <td id="e">5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="f">6</td>
    <td id="g">7</td>
    <td id="h">8</td>
    <td id="i">9</td>
    <td id="j">10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Click" onclick="clickhere();" />
```